# Java: Is there a shortcut for doing this (simple accessors/getters stuff)

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class called Person:

```
public class Person 
{
    private String name, ID, location;
}
```

Instead of writing individual accessors for name, ID, and location, is there anyway to do something like this:

```
public String get%s 
{
    return this.%s
}
```

Where "%s" stands as a sort of place holder for the name of the String which I want to "get". This way, for the sake of convenience and efficiency, I will be able to write one method to access all three Strings. Thanks.

Comment: No such thing.  Try another language.  Or, better yet, use an IDE like IntelliJ that generates them automagically for you.  This is not a deal breaker.

Comment: Thanks Kay. Looks Interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't have this feature, but if you use Eclipse, you can automatically generate setters and getters for your class members.

Comment: Here are the steps to do it: RightClick in file -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of anything like that in Java, but Groovy does almost exactly that, exposes JavaBean get/sets as if they were just public.

```
class Person {
    private String name
    private String location
    private String id

    String toString() {
        "Person( name: $name, location: $location, id: $id )"
    }
}

def bob = new Person()
bob.name = "bob";
bob.location = "seattle"

def robert = new Person( name: "robert", location: "seattle" )

println "bob is $bob, robert is $robert"
```

It works with your old school JavaBeans as well.  Give groovy a try, it has stuff that Java should have had all along and it interoperates with Java with no impedance mismatch (an ints and int, a BigDecimal is a BigDecimal, I can get all all my Jars, the list goes on and on).

By-in-large, JavaBean get and set method generation has become the function of the IDEs.  In Eclipse, you set up your member variables, then select "Source, Generate Getters and Setters..." and select which fields you want to expose an how.

Comment: Funny how my answer suggesting Groovy got downvoted and yours upvoted ;). Anyway +1, I think that it's the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/), which generates getters and setters at compile time.

Quotes from the [feature overview](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html):

> @Getter / @Setter:
>   Never write public int getFoo() {return foo;} again.
>
> @ToString:
>   No need to start a debugger to see your fields: Just let lombok generate a toString for you!
>
> @Data:
>   All together now: A shortcut for @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter on all fields, and @Setter on all non-final fields, and @RequiredArgsConstructor!

Your Person class would seems like the perfect target for an `@Data` annotation.

I use Lombok together with JSF and Hibernate in NetBeans and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such a thing in Java.

You can use [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) (works perfectly well in a Java project mixed with Java classes), you won't have to worry about declaring getters and setters anymore.